# Xcode 9.1 (9B55) failed to export with "Stripping extended attributes failed"

Tags: xcode9.1

Xcode 9.1 (9B55) failed to export with error of `Stripping extended attributes failed` and below error message:

```
/usr/bin/xattr -crs /var/folders/mm/h01jykrs7gv9w7jjb0yt609w0000gp/T/XcodeDistPipeline.FZT/Root/Payload/GitSmartHome.app" exited with a non-zero status. The /usr/bin/xattr tool may be damaged.
```

In IDEDistributionPipeline.log, can see below error:

```
2017-11-01 14:02:24 +0000
2017-11-01 14:02:24 +0000  Running /usr/bin/xattr '-crs' '/var/folders/mm/h01jykrs7gv9w7jjb0yt609w0000gp/T/XcodeDistPipeline.U1x/Root/Payload/GitSmartHome.app'
2017-11-01 14:02:24 +0000  option -c not recognized
usage: xattr [-lz] file [file ...]
       xattr -p [-lz] attr_name file [file ...]
       xattr -w [-z] attr_name attr_value file [file ...]
       xattr -d attr_name file [file ...]
The first form lists the names of all xattrs on the given file(s).
The second form (-p) prints the value of the xattr attr_name.
The third form (-w) sets the value of the xattr attr_name to attr_value.
The fourth form (-d) deletes the xattr attr_name.
options:
  -h: print this help
  -l: print long format (attr_name: attr_value)
  -z: compress or decompress (if compressed) attribute value in zip format
2017-11-01 14:02:24 +0000  2017-11-01 14:02:24 +0000
2017-11-01 14:02:24 +0000  /usr/bin/xattr exited with 64
```

I searched and tried a lot from the web before see this error, the question is how to fix or reinstall xattr or python of original MacOS?
Does re-install High Sierra fix that?

Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: The issue was fixed via re-install High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Hello，Has your problem been resolved ? I get the same problem with you.
[image]

Comment: It may be caused by Mac python damage, and was fixed by re-install MacOS entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that maybe help you. 
I run cmd "/usr/bin/xattr -crs ***" in terminal and get:

```
python version 2.7.14 can't run /usr/bin/xattr.  Try the alternative(s): 
/usr/bin/xattr-2.7 (uses python 2.7)
```

then I run cmd

```
$ sudo mv xattr xattr_bak
$ sudo mv xattr-2.7 xattr
```

it worked in my xcode9.1.